# I can't run Angular server I replace angular.json file and I get the same error

Tags: angular

I can't run Angular server - I tried to figure out the problem and I can't get it

> An unhandled exception occurred: Workspace config file cannot le loaded: F:\me\angular test\angtest\angular.json
>
> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>   Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
>
> See "C:\Users\chetos\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-eg8i0c\angular-errors.log" for further details.
>
> PS F:\me\angular test\angtest> ng s
>   Your global Angular CLI version (8.1.1) is greater than your local
>   version (8.0.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
>   Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
>
> Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
>
> at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (F:\me\angular test\angtest\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:49:19)
>   at ServeCommand.initialize (F:\me\angular test\angtest\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:135:55)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
>   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>   at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Comment: Can you share your angular.json file?

Comment: how can send you this file

Comment: Any code or config must be added to the question itself, by editing the question and using the formatting tools provided.